# How do I disable presenter console in Libreoffice 4

Tags: multiple-monitors, libreoffice

I am enjoying libreoffice 4, but don't want to have presenter console on because we do multiple things during a presentation, and the console window blocks out any option for switching windows or system volume or other simple things like seeing the time. 
I have been down the road of "extensions" but it is built into the core of libreoffice 4 and cannot be just unticked in the tools extensions menu. 
How do I remove, or at very lease disable it? It seems many other people want to know.

---

It seems this is renamed in libreoffice 4.1 (or its a kubuntu issue) to libpresenterconsole.so 
Make sure you are renaming the right thing.

Comment: The solution to rename the file works like a charm! Just would like to add a comment that for Libre Office Version: 4.2.1.1 on Ubuntu, the file has been renamed to and located in /opt/libreoffice4.2/program/libPresenterScreenlo.so

Comment: *I am not Impressed.*

Answer (score 9):

I think the easiest and cleanest way to proceed is to go to Tools/Options/Impress/General and disable the option "Enable Presenter Console".

#### NB: You must be in LibreOffice Impress for this option to show up.

Comment: In version 5.1.6.2 it's Tools -> Options... -> LibreOffice Impress -> General -> Presentation -> Enable Presenter Console.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the console script is burried in the core of libreoffice 4, so upon a quick search of the filesystem for "presenter" I found "PresenterScreen.uno.so" in the /usr/lib/libreoffice/program folder. A simple renaming of that file to PresenterScreen.uno.so.hidethis (or something else) disables the presenter console. 
So to recap, open nautilus as root, or use a terminal and go to /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/PresenterScreen.uno.so and rename it to something else, but don't have to delete it.
I hope a lot of people see this. It is much easier to multi task during a presentation when the presenter console is running, though it is very smooth and slick, but is not mature yet. I do enjoy it, but the group I work with does not, and the console removes all options for file navigation, and opening another presentation, changing volume, playing solitaire (just kidding). 
Thanks everyone.